# Akka Test TCP command failed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I am trying to write my first Akka test and going through the documentation. I was running the very first [example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#asynchronous-testing-testkit) of it and getting following error:

> [ERROR] [10/26/2017 14:08:55.371] [IngestionWorkerActorSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://IngestionWorkerActorSpec/user/$b] 
>    Assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for Test message
>   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for Test message

Below is the receive method of my test actor:

```
override def receive: Receive = {
case p: ProducerRecord[_,_] =>
      sendChannel.send(p.value())
case _ => logger.error("Unknown type Producer Record Received.")
}
```

Testspec:

```
val uutActor =system.actorOf(IngestionWorkerActor.props(config, KafkaProducer))
"An actor must send " should  {
"send back messages unchanged" in {
  uutActor ! expected
  Thread.sleep(50)
  expectMsg(expected)
}
}
```

I wanted to test whether my actor is receiving the messages sent to it or not and later I wanted to modify it to see whether I am getting specific message or not. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`expectMsg(something)` means that the actor would reply with `something` to `sender()` (which was captured by an implicit parameter to `!` when you sent the message), it does not introspect the messages the actor receives.

Best practice would be to avoid trying to write tests that look into the internal of actors but instead verify that they behave as they should when messages are sent. In this case that could maybe be to put a mock `sendChannel` in there and verify that the right value was sent on it.